# Partial declarations must not specify different base classes in Silverlight gadget

Tags: c#, silverlight, widget

I am developing a Silverlight gadget for Windows widget. When I add another page in my widget then I found this error.
I found in Stack Overflow same question, but it was not for widget.

My sample code is here XAML code

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="SilverlightGadgetDocked.Test" 
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
           xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
           d:DesignWidth="359" d:DesignHeight="225"
           Title="Test Page">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,103,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

and cs code is here,

```
public partial class Test:UserControl
    {
        public Test()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("af");
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code behind specified a base class of `UserControl` but your XAML file specifies a base class of `Page` (the root node of the document corresponds to the base class of the type).

Change

```
public partial class Test:UserControl
```

To

```
public partial class Test
```

And all will be well.  It's worth noting that you don't actually have to specify base classes on all parts of a partial class.  Since the base class is set in the XAML file, there's no need to specify it again on the class in the code behind (but, if you did, it'd have to match the type specified in the XAML).

Comment: But I cant navigate this page from main page in silverlight gadget

Comment: How can I navigate this test page to my main page in silverlight gadget,there is no references for silverlight gadget all are as usual.

Comment: @Asik I'm sorry, I haven't worked with Silverlight gadgets, your question appeared to be about a compiler error (relating to the mismatched base classes). You'll probably want to open a new question about navigation in gadgets.